# visualizing a binary tree (BST)

Tags: c, function, binary-tree, visualization, draw

i have some errors in this function that do the visualization of a binary tree, first of all we have to open the file in writing mode then draw the tree in it.
then we have to generate the (.png) file with the commande(it's in the code) in order to visualize our picture.
PS: in this code the parts  creating a tree (creer_arbre) and printing it (afficher_arbre) work perfectly but when it comes to the function of drawing (dessinnerarbre) the programme just stop working.

```
void dessinArbre (Pointeur_ATib R, FILE* f, int* nbNil)//the function of drawing
{
    if (R != NULL)
    {  
        // Dessiner un arc vers le fils gauche
        if (Fg_ATib(R) != NULL)
        {  
            fprintf(f, "  \"%d\" -- \"%d\" \n", Info_ATib(R), Info_ATib(Fg_ATib(R)));
            
        }
        else
        {   
            fprintf(f, "  \"NIL%d\" [style=invis];\n", *nbNil);
            fprintf(f, "  \"%d\" -- \"NIL%d\" ", Info_ATib(R), (*nbNil)++);
            fprintf(f, " [style=invis];\n");
        }
       
        // Dessiner un fils NIL virtuel et invisible au milieu (pour une meilleure séparation des fils gauches et droits)
        fprintf(f, "  \"NIL%d\" [style=invis];\n", *nbNil);
        fprintf(f, "  \"%d\" -- \"NIL%d\" ", Info_ATib(R), (*nbNil)++);
        fprintf(f, " [style=invis];\n");
  
        // Dessiner un arc vers le fils droit
        if (Fd_ATib(R)!= NULL)
        { 
            fprintf(f, "  \"%d\" -- \"%d\" \n", Info_ATib(R), Info_ATib(Fd_ATib(R)));
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(f, "  \"NIL%d\" [style=invis];\n", *nbNil);
            fprintf(f, "  \"%d\" -- \"NIL%d\" ", Info_ATib(R), (*nbNil)++);
            fprintf(f, " [style=invis];\n");
        }
 
        // Dessiner les sous-arbres gauche et droit
        dessinArbre(Fg_ATib(R), f, nbNil);
        dessinArbre(Fd_ATib(R), f, nbNil);
        
   }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) //the main programme
    {
        FILE* f;
        char*nomf;
        int sortie;
        int nbNil=0;
        char*cmd;

     printf ( " %s", " Introduiser le nombre des elements dans l'arbre " ) ;
     scanf ( " %d", &N ) ;
    /* lecture de nombre des elments */
     Creer_arbre ( & P, & N ) ;
     Afficher ( & P ) ;
    //dessin du  notre arbre
    printf ("Dessin de l'arbre \n");
                    printf ("   ----------------- \n\n");
                    if (P == NULL)
                    {
                        printf ("> ERREUR : Arbre vide !");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sprintf(nomf, "arbre%d.dot", sortie);
                        f = fopen(nomf,"w");        // Ouverture du fichier en écriture.
                        fprintf(f, "graph arbre {\n");
                        fprintf(f, "\tordering = out;\n");
                        fprintf(f, "\tsplines = false;\n");
                        nbNil = 0;
                        dessinArbre(P, f, &nbNil);
                        fprintf(f, "}\n");
                        fclose(f);
                        sprintf(cmd, "dot -Tpng arbre%d.dot -o arbre%d.png", sortie);
                        system(cmd);
                        sprintf(cmd, "arbre%d.png", sortie);
                        system(cmd);
                        sortie++;
                        printf (">> L'arbre est dessine correctement !");
                    }

     // system("PAUSE");
     getchar();
      return 0;
    }
```

this is the implementation:

```
typedef struct Tib Type_Tib  ;
  typedef Type_Tib * Typestr_Tib ;
  typedef int Type1_Tib  ;
  typedef bool Type2_Tib  ;
  struct Tib
    {
      Type1_Tib Champ1 ;
      Type2_Tib Champ2 ;
    };

  Type1_Tib Struct1_Tib ( Typestr_Tib S)
    {
      return  S->Champ1 ;
    }

  Type2_Tib Struct2_Tib ( Typestr_Tib S)
    {
      return  S->Champ2 ;
    }

  void Aff_struct1_Tib ( Typestr_Tib S, Type1_Tib Val )
    {
       S->Champ1 = Val ;
    }

  void Aff_struct2_Tib ( Typestr_Tib S, Type2_Tib Val )
    {
       S->Champ2 = Val ;
    }


  /** Arbres de recherche binaire **/

  typedef Typestr_Tib Typeelem_ATib   ;
  typedef struct Noeud_ATib * Pointeur_ATib ;

  struct Noeud_ATib
    {
      Typeelem_ATib  Val ;
      Pointeur_ATib Fg ;
      Pointeur_ATib Fd ;
      Pointeur_ATib Pere ;
     } ;
```

Comment: "*just stop working*". Where did it stop working? What was it doing? These can be answered by debugging the code. Either run in a debugger and/or add more debug print statements. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You need to show a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

```
char*nomf;
//...
    sprintf(nomf, "arbre%d.dot", sortie);
```

`nomf` needs to be a pointer to a buffer of appropriate size. A simple fix would be to declare `nomf` as `char nomf[256];` Consider using a debugger to inspect your program at runtime, a decent debugger will tell you exactly where your program is crashing.

Comment: Better always use `snprintf()`.